# Git: Create branch from several specific commits that are in order but between hundreds of other commits

Tags: git, github

So I have a branch that I have royally messed up, and it now has over 300 commits to it, which I can see is older commits that belong to other branches that made their way to master.

I basically just want the branch to look like it did before I broke it. I can create new one also if neccesary, I just want to push the branch again and it must have like the 10 commits that was there originally.

Meaning I want it to start at a specific commit, and end at a specific commit. Those commits are currently on the branch in question, they are also directly after each other, they are just preceded but 300 commits which I do not want.

Comment: The appropriate solution depends on how you "broke" the branch. Can you link to your repository? If not, can you post the output of `git log --oneline --graph -- decorate` for the relevant parts? The specific log messages don't matter, the topography and branch heads do.

Comment: Go back to the last commit you want to keep before the 300 undesired commits (with git checkout), then cherry-pick the 10 commits you want to keep after the undesired 300 commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps.

1. Create a new branch at the desired commit you need to start your branch in question, and check it out.
2. Cherry pick each commit you actually need in your branch to new branch, in the correct order (Since there are only 10 commits you need, this should be easy).
3. Hard reset the branch in question to the commit the new branch is now pointing at.

If there were large number of commits that you want in your branch and small number of commits you need to remove, you can interactively rebase (`git rebase -i`) the branch in question onto the new branch, after step 1 above (It will interactively ask you the commits you need to add, and commits you need to ignore).

Before you start, it is better to create a new branch at the same commit your branch in question pointing at, so you can easily recover if you mess up. Backing up the full repository before starting is also a good idea.